# AsynchronousServerSocketChannel finally block never executed

Tags: java, asynchronous, serversocket, socketchannel

I create AsynchronousServerSocketChannel and everything is fine untill I want close server socket socket.
I create AsynchronousSocketChannel on client with special message which call function to close server and all socket channels, server is closed but finnally block is never executed why?

Check code:

```
 public void openServerSocket(int sport) {


    port = sport;
    policyFile = createPolicy(new String[]{"*:"+port});
    try {

        //group = AsynchronousChannelGroup.withThreadPool(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
        //group.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        server = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open();
        server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(sport));


        server.accept(null, this);

       while(isOpen) {

            //System.out.println("running server socket");

        }
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        this.message = ex.getMessage();
        System.out.println("Server: " + ex.getMessage());
    }finally {

        System.out.println("Finall serversocket closing!");
        for(SocketHandler sh : sockets) {
            sh.close();
        }

        if(server != null) {
            try {
                server.close();
                server = null;
            }catch(Exception ex2) {
                this.message = ex2.getMessage();
            }
        }


        sockets.clear();
        sockets = null;
        //this.message = "server socket closed";

        System.out.println("server socket down");
    }

}

@Override
public void completed(AsynchronousSocketChannel socket, Void attachment) {

    System.out.println("new connection");
    SocketHandler sh = new SocketHandler(socket, this);

    server.accept(null, this);
}

@Override
public void failed(Throwable exc, Void attachment) {

    System.out.println("Server Failed accept:" + exc.getMessage());
}


public void closeServerSocket() {

    System.out.println("Closing server socket! " + server);
    this.isOpen = false;

}
```

So function closeServerSocket is called and I set false to variable isOpen which keep looping, but seems when I set false to isOpen var, while is still looping and finally is never executed?

Comment: Does `isOpen` ever change to be `false`?

Comment: Yes its changed but no effect on loop I dont know why :(

Comment: Could you show us the declaration of `isOpen` and where it changes?

Comment: Now I call print line function isnide while loop and something happend very strange.

System.out.println("running server socket");
System.out.println(this.isOpen);

When I have this print line inside while loop isOpen is changed and finally block is executed, when I remove printline in while loop, while is still running this is unbelievably. Now I will record video, is this some bug or what?

Comment: check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aGzRIpdInZM&feature=youtu.be

Comment: solved with while(server.isOpen()) and while(socket.isOpen())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks looks like an issue of communication between several threads. From the code I guess that your `while(isOpen)` loop runs in a different thread than the `closeServerSocket()` method of your class. To verify this add `Thread.currentThread()` to your print statements.

If this is the case, you can remedy the situation by declaring `isOpen` to be `volatile`. Without the `volatile` it is not guaranteed, if and when any other thread will see the written value. With the `volatile` it is guaranteed that (my interpretation of [happens-before](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility)) a thread accessing the variable **later** (according to wall clock time) will see the changed value.

Instead of `volatile` you may prefer an `AtomicBoolean`.

Comment: Ok I will test this. but for now I check serversocket and socket directly in while, while(server.isOpen()) and while(socket.isOpen()) and its work, I also think that is by thread I will test your suggestion and inform you.

Comment: Yes AtomicBoelan also helped, so developers can use AtomicBoolean or inside loop call socket.isOpen() wich is also helpful and resolve the problem as AtomicBoolean. Thanks Harald